# How to read a file character by character until a specific string is complete?

Tags: java

I'm struggling with this concept for a problem I have. I wrote a compression algorithm that compresses text files based on a list of character to code pairs that are stored in objects within an array. Now when decompressing I've realized I have to read each the file character by character until a string is created that matches one of the codes, write the character that that code corresponds to, and keep iterating over the file until it's finished.

I'm not too certain where to go from here, but here is what I have so far:

```
 CompressedFile compFile = new CompressedFile(args[0],"read");
    TextFile outFile = new TextFile(args[0].substring(0,args[0].lastIndexOf('.') )+".dec","write");

    String output = "";
    String temp = "";
    char charac = 0;
    check = false;

    while(!check) {
    charac =compFile.readBit();
    if(charac==(char)0) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    temp=compressionCodes.getCharacter((compressionCodes.findCode(charac)));
```

There's a lot more that's missing but it shouldn't really be important, it's just this loop that I'm really struggling with.

Comment: Just to clarify, what's the exactly the format of the file that you expect? Is it basically something like:  "blahblahblah123blahblahblah" and when you scan 123, you've therefore found a substring of the file that matches an opcode?  Or does  DHARMENDRA SINGH have it right where basically the first characters of the file match an opcode.

Comment: The format of the file im writing to is going to be regular text, anything from blahblah13 to an essay. I'm reading bits that are converted to characters, so I read 123 like you said (except they are symbols from a compressed file) and once i hit the full string 123 it realizes that thats the code for the character "a" and writes a to the output file.

Comment: So I guess what I mean is is the code a substring of the file, or is it always gonna be the first characters in the file.

Comment: The code is stored in as part of an object in an array. The array stores information as [character, code]. There are roughly 255 character and code combinations, all are unique. As I'm reading the compressed file, I need to iterate over each character and add them to a string and then once that string matches one of the codes in the array, write the corresponding character to the output file.

Comment: So then the top answer solves your problem. One small optimization I would suggest is that instead of storing things as an array, store it as a Map. Maps basically give you very fast equality checks. In otherwords, where the top answer writes concatString.equal(specificString), replace with opCodes.contains(concatString). Where opCodes is a map containing your substring to opcode conversion.

Comment: I don't think I'm supposed to use a buffered reader as I have methods to read the file already, it's just iterating over it and then adding to a temp string and matching it to the array that I don't understand how to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample complete program that I have that illustrates how you can potentially do a match. NOTE: Using an array to store associations is a BAD IDEA if you have lookup performance. However, if you have to use an array, you simply need to iterate over the array, looking for the first lookup association that matches your search criteria.

Source

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class OpCodeLookupService {

Pair[] opCodes;

public static final class Pair {
    String first;
    String second;

    public Pair(String first, String second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }
}

public OpCodeLookupService(Pair[] opCodes) {
    this.opCodes = opCodes;
}

public Pair pairLookup(String toLookup) {
    for(Pair p : this.opCodes) {
        if (p.first.equals(toLookup)) {
            return p;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public String lookup(String filePath) {
    try {
        // In the comments, you mentioned you cannot use BufferedReader to ingest the file. In this example, I'm showing another way via Scanner which is a very easy to use class for ingesting input streams.
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(filePath));
        StringBuilder stringToExamine = new StringBuilder();
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            String nextString = s.next();
            for (char c : nextString.toCharArray()) {
                stringToExamine.append(c);
                Pair pair = pairLookup(stringToExamine.toString());
                if (pair != null) {
                    return pair.second;
                }
            }
        }
        return null; //Indicates string is not found.
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot load file");
    }
}


public static void main(String...args) {
    final Pair p = new Pair("thisisopcode", "12345");
    Pair[] pairs = new Pair[1];
    pairs[0] = p;
    OpCodeLookupService opService = new OpCodeLookupService(pairs);
    System.out.println(opService.lookup("/Users/liuben10/foo.txt"));
  }
}
```

So given a text file that looks like this:

"thisisopcodeklajsdfklajdsfkljadf",

It would output:

"12345"

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
         new FileInputStream(fName),"utf-8"));
int k;
String concatString ="";
while((k =rd.read())!=-1){
    if(concatString.equal(specificString) break;
    else concatString += (char)k;
}
```

// break the while loop when string match